# React native expo push notification not working in Android

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, push-notification, expo

I am developing a react native expo app. Basically, I tried to use expo notifications to send push notifications. But the notification only shows up in IOS devices but not on android devices.

Below are some snippets that might be suspicious.

[The notification listen on the global scope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEysR.png)
[Initialize the expo token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfTG3.png)

App.json:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "scheme": "mobileApp",
    "name": "mobileApp",
    "slug": "mobileApp",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "icon": "./assets/images/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.study.buddyyyyy",
      "buildNumber": "26"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "permissions": [
        "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
        "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
        "android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE",
        "android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"
      ]
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-location",
        {
          "locationAlwaysAndWhenInUsePermission": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to use your location."
        }
      ],
      [
        "expo-image-picker",
        {
          "photosPermission": "The app accesses your photos to let you share them with your friends."
        }
      ],
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "ios": {
            "useFrameworks": "static"
          }
        }
      ]
    ],
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "f29924bc-c60c-4993-b528-eaf70eb53b0c"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tested the local scheduled notifications on android and it is working. This can exclude the possibility of permissions.
The expo token was retrieved successfully.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you missed the most important config.

For Android, you need to configure Firebase Cloud Messaging **(FCM)**, otherwise, it should not work out of the box.

check this link with all steps you should follow =>  https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/push-notifications-setup/#android